# How can I calculate P-Value for a custom distribution?

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, distributions, parameters

I used `DistributionFitTest` but it works only with a defined distribution.

This is the distribution that I used:

```
 dist = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", 
   Divide[(E^-(1 - E^(-\[Lambda]*x))^\[Alpha]) - 1, (E^-1) - 1]}, {x, 
   0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {\[Lambda] > 0, \[Alpha] > 0}];
```

This is the data that I used:

```
 data = { 70,  90,  96,  97,  99, 103, 104, 104, 105, 107, 108, 108, 108, 109,
            109 ,112, 112 ,113 ,114 ,114 ,114, 116 ,119 ,120, 120, 120, 121, 121,
            123 ,124, 124 ,124, 124, 124 ,128, 128 ,129 ,129 ,130, 130, 130, 131,
            131, 131 ,131 ,131 ,132, 132, 132 ,133, 134, 134, 134 ,134 ,136 ,136,
            137, 138 ,138, 138, 139, 139, 141, 141 ,142 ,142 ,142, 142, 142 ,142,
            142, 142, 144 ,144 ,145 ,146 ,148 ,148, 149, 151 ,151 ,152 ,155, 156,
            155 ,156 ,157 ,157 ,157 ,157, 158 ,159, 162, 163 ,163, 164 ,166 ,166,
            168, 170 ,174, 201 ,212}
```

I used this function to calculate MLE for parameters:

```
mle = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist, 
  ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
```

And I get:

```
{\[Alpha] -> 196.82, \[Lambda] -> 0.0402896}
```

When I use:

```
DistributionFitTest[data, 
 dist/. {\[Alpha] -> 33.95145437178186`, \[Lambda] -> 
    0.04938113418195074`}, {"TestDataTable", "KolmogorovSmirnov"}]
```

It takes a long time and returns no answer, instead I get `$Aborted`.

But when I use a defined distribution like `WeibullDistribution[a, b]` it works.

Comment: If the complete set of tests turns out not to be available with `DistributionFitTest` for your distribution, what tests do you need?  ("AndersonDarling", "CramerVonMises", "JarqueBeraALM", "KolmogorovSmirnov", "Kuiper", "PearsonChiSquare", "ShapiroWilk", "WatsonUSquare")

Comment: @JimB: Even `data = DeleteDuplicates[{70,...,212}]` together with   "PearsonChiSquare" do not work.

Comment: @user64494 Because `DistributionFitTest` doesn't work for any of the tests, I was fishing for what test was needed so that it could be coded from scratch without `DistributionFitTest`.  I should have been more complete in my comment.

Comment: how about simply to use MCMC?